# Search fails after upgrade to TFS 2018 Update 2

Tags: elasticsearch, tfs

After performing an upgrade of a TFS server to 2018 Update 2 the search and indexing seems to be broken on one of our environments.

Any search gives "We encountered an unexpected error when processing your request" and I have work through all the troubleshooting docs to clean and reindex all collections. Also completely reinstalled the search package to the separate server we run for search and indexing to make sure we got the correct version running.

In the event logs on the TFS App Server a large number of these exceptions are logged:

> Events (81277) completed with status FailedAndRetry. Event 81277
>   completed with message 'BeginBulkIndex-PushEventNotification: The
>   operation did not complete successfully because of exception
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Common.FeederException: Lots of
>   files rejected by Elasticsearch, failing this job. Failure Reason :
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Common.SearchPlatformException:
>   ES Exception: [HTTP Status Code: [200] BULK_API_ERROR: [ index
>   returned 404 _index: codesearchshared_1_0 _type:
>   SourceNoDedupeFileContractV3 _version: 0 error: Type:
>   type_missing_exception Reason: "type[SourceNoDedupeFileContractV3]
>   missing"

And another exception type also logged a lot of times indicating failure to index work items:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Search.Common.SearchPlatformException:
>   ES Exception: [HTTP Status Code: [200] BULK_API_ERROR: [  update
>   returned 404 _index: workitemsearchshared_0_2 _type: workItemContract
>   _version: 0 error: Type: type_missing_exception Reason: "type[workItemContract] missing"  update returned 404 _index:
>   workitemsearchshared_0_2 _type: workItemContract _version: 0 error:
>   Type: type_missing_exception Reason: "type[workItemContract] missing"

The exceptions seems to indicate that some type registrations are missing like the workItemContract and SourceNoDedupeFileContractV3 but I can not find any errors on the search server installation logs.

Anyone got some suggestions on how to solve this and get the Elastic Search back into a working state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We resolved to situation by completely uninstalling and then reinstalling everything related to search.

1. Uninstalled all Code/Work/Wiki extensions from all collections from the extension management in web admin
2. Removed the TFS Search Service feature from the TFS Admin Console.
3. Uninstalled the elasticsearch service from the separate search server, using the PowerShell script .\Configure-TFSSearch.ps1 -operation remove
4. Restart TFS Job Agent service
5. Deleted old Search related databas content from ALL collection databases using

   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnit]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEvent]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_IndexingUnitChangeEventArchive]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_JobYield]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_TreeStore]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_DisabledFiles]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_ItemLevelFailures]
   >
   > DELETE FROM [Search].[tbl_ResourceLockTable]
6. Restart TFS Job Agent service
7. Reboot Search server
8. Run Configure Search feature wizard from TFS Admin Console, using existing search server
9. Install search package according to instructions by PowerShell script

   > .\Configure-TFSSearch.ps1 -Operation install -TFSSearchInstallPath
   >   D:\ES -TFSSearchIndexPath D:\ESDATA -Port 9200 -Verbose
10. Completed Search configuration wizard from TFS Admin Console enabling code search for all existing collections
11. Checked that services were running and tested searching from the web application, it works!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your error info and TFS version, this issue similar to  [Unable to start search after upgrade to TFS 2018 Update 2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/262182/unable-to-start-search-after-upgrade-to-tfs-2018-u.html)

Try the solution in the question below:

> It seemed that I had an invalid/problematic setting in following reg
>   key that update/install did not fix.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Procrun
>   2.0\elasticsearch-service-x64\Parameters\Java\Options
>
> Value contained:
>
> -Xms0m
>   -Xmx0m
>
> Changing both from '0m' to '1g' fixed the issue. As far as I
>   understand '0m' defaults to 4GB, which might collide with my server
>   only having 2,8 GB of RAM. I will upgrade the server to follow the
>   minimum requirements.
>
> Maybe the configuration tool could warn about this problem or set the
>   value to something that is possible.

Also take a look at this article, which maybe helpful: [*Elasticsearch 6.2.2 fails to run as a windows service*](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28860)

Comment: No, we had a look at that article already and our service was starting and running but something made it refuse to understand requests from TFS App service.

Answer (score 0):

[This post refers to azure devops server 2019 to 2020 upgrade]

I also got
"We encountered an unexpected error when processing your request"
for any search - this was after migrating azure devops server 2019 to 2020 on a new box (was unable to perform the upgrade on the same box)

http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v showed the only cluster TFS_Search_AZURE-DEVOPS in red status

In my particular case everything on the same box - windows 2019 + sql server 2019 + search service

Followed Per Salmi instructions and unfortunately that did not resolve the issue.

The **solution** in my case was rebuilding elastic search indexes ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2019#reindex-a-repository-or-collection) and [scripts](https://github.com/microsoft/Code-Search/tree/master/Azure_DevOps_Server_2019)):

1. Reindex repo

To reindex a Git or TFVC repository, execute the appropriate version of the script **Re-IndexingCodeRepository.ps1** for your Azure DevOps Server or TFS version with administrative privileges. You're prompted to enter: [my values in brackets]
The SQL server instance name where the Azure DevOps Server or TFS configuration database is [azure-devops]
The name of the Azure DevOps Server or TFS collection database [Tfs_DefaultCollection]
The name of the Azure DevOps Server or TFS configuration database [Tfs_Configuration]
The type of reindexing to execute. Can be one of the following values: Git_Repository TFVC_Repository [Git_Repository]
The name of the collection [DefaultCollection]
The name of the repository to reindex. [your repo name here]

2. Reindex collection

To reindex a collection, execute the script **TriggerCollectionIndexing.ps1** with administrative privileges. You're prompted to enter: [my values in brackets]
The SQL server instance name where the Azure DevOps Server or TFS configuration database is [azure-devops]
The name of the Azure DevOps Server or TFS collection database [Tfs_DefaultCollection]
The name of the Azure DevOps Server or TFS configuration database [Tfs_Configuration]
The name of the collection [DefaultCollection]
The entities to reindex. Can be one of the following values: All Code WorkItem Wiki [All]

The scripts above place reindexing jobs that typically take a few minutes to complete.

Right after execution I was getting an encouraging "We are not able to show results because one or more projects in your organization are still being indexed"

And after a few minutes results started to come in, http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?v showing the only cluster TFS_Search_AZURE-DEVOPS in green status